# Incorrect DECIMAL value when inserting MySQL 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Name  Type

price decimal(7,0)

```
INSERT INTO products (uid, item_code,item_name, brand_name,model_number,weight,dimension,description,category,quantity,price,imagename) 
VALUES (1, '01','Lenovo','Lenovo laptop','qwqeiu145','50kg','5x9','Lenovo is the best','Computers & Accessories','2','$250.0000','lenovo');
```

THIS IS THE ERROR

> 1366 - Incorrect decimal value: '$250.0000' for column 'price' at row
>   1

Comment: If you check your error message correct you will see that there is a string value like @alivetoDie suggested.If you have to put the currency into the table you can create an extra column for the currency

Answer (score 4):

You need to Change

```
$250.0000
```

To

```
250.0000
```

because it's `decimal` datatype. You can only insert numbers in it, while `$` is a string

Answer (score 0):

In decimal fields you can only insert numbers, you just need to remove the `$`.

Take care u declared the field with 0 decimals, any number after the dot will be ignored.